# I am getting error when i was trying to connect to mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql

```
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime

def createUsers():
    with mysql.connector.connect(host="sql.freedb.tech",user="freedb_sami9644",password="########",database="freedb_messangerpro_db") as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        # cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users")
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE users(\
                    fullname TEXT,\
                    username TEXT PRIMARY KEY,\
                    birthdate DATE,\
                    gender TEXT,\
                    country TEXT,\
                    avatar TEXT,\
                    password TEXT,\
                    session TEXT,\
                    createdon DATE)")
createUsers()
```

The error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\sam\Desktop\MegaFolder\MyApps\flask app\messanger\databases.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
  File "C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    from .pooling import connect
  File "C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\pooling.py", line 43, in <module>
    import dns.resolver
  File "C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 30, in <module>
    import dns._ddr
  File "C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\dns\_ddr.py", line 12, in <module>
    import dns.nameserver
  File "C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\dns\nameserver.py", line 5, in <module>
    import dns.asyncquery
  File "C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\dns\asyncquery.py", line 38, in <module>
    from dns.query import (
  File "C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\dns\query.py", line 67, in <module>
    _CoreNetworkBackend = httpcore.NetworkBackend
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'httpcore' has no attribute 'NetworkBackend'
```

I was expectig it to be connected to the database and creates a user table for my messanger web app

Comment: Hello, I found the answer here [issue](https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython/issues/970).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In old version of `httpcore`, the `NetworkBackend` attribute was present. However, this attribute was removed in the new  updates. This change leads to the `AttributeError` when the older version of the library tries to access it.

it can be fixed by upgrading the `httpcore` package to the current version by using this  command in the terminal.

`pip install — upgrade httpcore`